# Kill side effects of aborted requests in django

Tags: django

Let's say I have a request that runs a lengthy SQL query server side. The client gives up waiting and closes the browser. Will that query continue to run? Can I somehow detect such situations and handle it or does Django handle it for me?

I'm concerned that DB is wasting CPU cycles and memory when the results of the query are no longer needed and hoping that there's a general solution to that problem.

Comment: You can wrap the requests in transactions.

Comment: Is it a problem that happens often? If you need to do that, it is that the SQL query is critical in your backend. Wouldn't it be more interesting to make that SQL query less critical?

Comment: @AlexandreS I don't understand your suggestion. I was hoping that there's a generic solution so that whenever such long queries appear, they will not keep consuming resources needlessly.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem but the transaction will keep running in the background even after the browser is closed, wouldn't it?

Comment: @clorz: it is not very easy to stop a request. If it works asynchronous, then you can, stop such task, but that is not trivial either. A transaction does not "commit" the changes, so the queries run, but will never really change something, since in the end, the queries are rolled back..

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm not worried about changes. A simple example of a stopped request: proxy or webserver timeout. The app server can not provide a response in the allocated time limit, request in the browser is dropped with 504. But app server keeps working on it. That is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to optimize your requests as much as you can: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/optimization/

Due to discsussion here: https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/521

> Well this is already the case: if the worker is blocked/frozen for any reason, gunicorn will kill it after a timeout. Using the worker_exit hook you can add a function that send a mail or any useful notification when it happen. It is relatively trivial to do it.

Instead of sending e-mails I advice to use https://sentry.io/welcome/ on worker_exit hook